# How can I become a master at the radios?

Tags: commercial-aviation, flight-training, radio-communications

Are there any resources for student pilots who wants to get better at the radios?

Currently, I am immersing myself by using liveatc.com but what I am looking for is perhaps scripts between pilot and ATC so that I can study them.

Comment: Once you realize that 90% of the comms are a vocabulary of, what, maybe 30-50 words, it takes a lot of the pressure off.

Answer (score 2):

Practice your radio calls with someone on the ground. It's best to work with another pilot or instructor. But, you can even practice with a friend or significant other.

You might find a script like this helpful: https://www.aopa.org/-/media/files/aopa/home/pilot-resources/asi/sampleradiocalls.pdf

Best of luck in your aviation journey.
-Matt

Answer (score 1):

I would look at services like [vatsim](https://www.vatsim.net/) which offer real controller/other pilot radio integration into some modern software simulators. You can practice taxi instructions, picking up flight following, tower comms for class B,C,D airports etc.

Live ATC as you have noted is a great option.

Fly right seat with certified pilots, ask to operate the radios. If you are learning to fly you are likely near the GA section of the airport, if you hang around and get to know people, make friends, and maybe wash a plane or two you can likely get some right seat time and some radio practice.

There are a lot of great, free, radio recordings on Youtube although many of them pertain to IFR clearance practice which can be helpful if and when you get to that stage.